# How can I improve this SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm checking for existing of a row in in_fmd, and the ISBN I look up can be the ISBN parameter, or another ISBN in a cross-number table that may or may not have a row.

```
select count(*)
from in_fmd i
where (description='GN')
    and ( i.isbn in
    (
        select bwi_isbn from bw_isbn where orig_isbn = ?
        union all
        select cast(? as varchar) as isbn
    )
)
```

I don't actually care about the count of the rows, but rather mere existence of at least one row.

This used to be three separate queries, and I squashed it into one, but I think there's room for more improvement.  It's PostgreSQL 8.1, if it matters.

Comment: As a sidenote, we're no longer using this query.  The in_fmd table has been removed and we don't have to synthesize the data point any more.  That query is fastest which does not run. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why bother with the `UNION ALL`

```
select count(*)
from in_fmd i
where (description='GN')
    and (
        i.isbn in (
            select bwi_isbn from bw_isbn where orig_isbn = ?
        )
        or i.isbn = cast(? as varchar)
    )
```

I would probably use a `LEFT JOIN`-style query instead of the `IN`, but that's more personal preference:

```
select count(*)
from in_fmd i
left join bw_isbn
    on bw_isbn.bwi_isbn = i.isbn
    and bw_isbn.orig_isbn = ?
where (i.description='GN')
    and (
        bw_isbn.bwi_isbn is not null
        or i.isbn = cast(? as varchar)
    )
```

The inversion discussed over IM:

```
SELECT SUM(ct)
FROM (
    select count(*) as ct
    from in_fmd i
    inner join bw_isbn
        on bw_isbn.bwi_isbn = i.isbn
        and bw_isbn.orig_isbn = ?
        and i.isbn <> cast(? as varchar)
        and i.description = 'GN'

    UNION

    select count(*) as ct
    from in_fmd i
    where i.isbn = cast(? as varchar)
        and i.description = 'GN'
) AS x
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't actually care about the count of the rows, but rather mere existence of at least one row.

Then how about querying `SELECT ... LIMIT 1` and checking in the calling program whether you get one result row or not?

Comment: I'd only be saving 1 row out of a max of 2.  I'm looking to do less looking up.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(ct)
FROM (select count(*) as ct
      from in_fmd i
      inner join bw_isbn
         on bw_isbn.bwi_isbn = i.isbn
        and bw_isbn.orig_isbn = ?
        and i.isbn <> cast(? as varchar)
        and i.description = 'GN'
      UNION
      select count(*) as ct
      from in_fmd i
      where i.isbn = cast(? as varchar)
        and i.description = 'GN'
     ) AS x
```

Answer (score 1):

apart from what other posters have noted , just changing

select count(*)

to

exists(..)

would [improve things](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/interactive/functions-subquery.html) quite a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*)
from in_fmd i
where description = 'GN'
  and exists (select 1 
              from bwi_isbn 
              where bw_isbn.bwi_isbn = in_fmd.isbn)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion